# How to center navigation arrows on website with css

Tags: html, css, center

I would like to place the navigation arrows you can see under "ervaringen" on this site: www.dedietiste.be at the left and right of the "stories". My knowledge of CSS is too little to pull this off, can someone help me?
Thank you

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please provide a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of your code so we can figure out *together* how to solve the issue

Comment: your link http://www.dedietiste.be is invisible, try to add it as link, to improve your chance of getting answers from others

Answer (score 0):

I visited the website and I am unsure what navigation arrows you are referring to. If you are looking to make a carousel/slideshow (where you can press the arrows on the side to show more content), then a helpful website is: https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_slideshow.asp
Other than that, provide some code you think would work and identify what arrows you are talking about. I looked under what you specified, but I only see some personal anecdotes in some boxes.